# move the row/s up when data matched with the inputted string

Tags: javascript

I need to move the row/s that is matched with the inputted string.
on the code below you need to click first the row before you can move that particular row to the top.

Instead of clicking the row, I just wanted to input a string or char then onclick, if there's a match on the html table, the row that matched or like on the string inputted will be moved on the top of the table grid.

```js
var index;

function getSelectedRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    table.rows[i].onclick = function() {

      if (typeof index !== "undefined") {
        table.rows[index].classList.toggle("selected");
      }

      index = this.rowIndex;
      this.classList.toggle("selected");

    };
  }

}


getSelectedRow();


function upNdown(direction) {

  var rows = document.getElementById("table").rows,
    parent = rows[index].parentNode;

  if (direction === "up") {
    if (index < rows.length) {
      parent.insertBefore(rows[index], rows[index - index + 1]);

      index--;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>C3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button onclick="upNdown('up');">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
```

what I need to do is upon click of the button, find the matching data and move the row to the top.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't want to have to click on a row before you can use the 'up arrow' button, that's right?

Comment: How do you check input string match any row??

Comment: Yes @sjahan I would simply just input a string on the input field then click on the up button to move up all the rows that has like or same data on the inputted char/string.

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee using match method.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you problem, Think this is your answer. This code find the first match of `input` and move that to first row. If the input be empty, it will do nothing.

```js
var index = 0;

function findMatchRow(rows, str) {
  if (!str.length) {
    return null;
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < rows[i].children.length; j++) {
      if (rows[i].children[j].textContent.match(str)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

function getSelectedRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
      if (typeof index !== "undefined") {
        table.rows[index].classList.toggle("selected");
      }

      index = this.rowIndex;
      this.classList.toggle("selected");
    };
  }
}

getSelectedRow();

function upNdown(direction) {
  var rows = document.getElementById("table").rows,
    parent = rows[index && index > -1 ? index : 0].parentNode,
    inpt = document.getElementById("txt").value;

  var matchedRow = findMatchRow(rows, inpt);
  if (matchedRow) {
    if (direction === "up") {
      index = matchedRow;
      parent.insertBefore(rows[index], rows[index - index + 1]);

      index--;
      if (index < 0) {
        index = rows.length - 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>C3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button onclick="upNdown('up');">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
```